# Is there and easy way to clone my windows 8 os from ssd to a larger ssd

Tags: ssd, operating-systems, windows-8-preview, clone

I know similar questions have been asked but, I have windows 8 preview release installed on an SSD (OCZ agility 3 120GB)

I want to just move all my stuff including OS to a larger SSD (OCZ vertex 4 512gb SSD)

Is this safe to do and if so how can I go about it (as easily as possible)?

Comment: Why bother cloning the RP when RTM's just around the corner (or already available depending on your access level)? In any case, if you want to do this software like Acronis should help.

Comment: Not sure what RP and RTM stand for, does Acronis need command line or anything or is it all GUI

Comment: RP = Release Preview, [RTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_to_manufacturing#RTM). [Acronis 2013 GUI](http://www.whatsabyte.com/images/ATI_2013_Review/True_Image_2013_1.jpg). Check the site for more, and of course there are alternatives too, including free ones (such as the Private Edition of DriveImage XML) that might suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BootIt Bare Metal](https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/bootit-bare-metal.htm).
It's program for managing your partitions, install and boot multiple operating systems with ease, back up and restore partitions or entire drives. Try to move partition (copy drive) and then see will it boot! (then delete files on your first drive). Also if you are condemned on installing windows I recommend [this site](https://ninite.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many pieces of software out there to clone drives, such as clonezilla, norton ghost, etc.

I prefer to use gparted and dd though.

Download and burn a gparted iso to disc, start up the live OS, check what the names of the drives are such as sda, sdb, sdc, sdz, etc.

Then open the terminal type in sudo bash to gain access to root.

Then type in dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M

Substitute sda for the drive your clone and sdb for the drive it goes to, if and of mean input and output, bs is the size of chunks of data that transfer, 1M being a decent speed with low chance of errors reoccurring causing dd to go longer.

For each 100 gigs of space you're looking at a hour or so.

This will make a exact clone of your drive, MBR and all so it will boot like the old drive would.